# rotating model while color updating

Tags: opengl, visualization, pyqt4, pyopengl

In OpenGL, I draw tree(composed of lines) like structure(neurons), and based on activity, i apply a color on each of the branches of the tree. Each branch portion may have a different color at an instance. I keep record of the color at an instance corresponding to the branch.

I am able to rotate (by changing the modelview matrix) the tree. I can see the changing color (activity) on the branches when updating.

However, i am not able to rotate the tree while the color change is happening. (the rotation is seen after the complete updating) This  is also true with translating the model, not able to translate while updating.

How should i be doing this to see them simultaneously?

i call the updateViz function to update the colors.

```
def render(self):
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    self.renderAxis()   #draws 3 axes at origin
    for obj in self.vizObjects:
        glPushMatrix()
        glColor(obj.r, obj.g, obj.b)
        glLineWidth(2)
        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        glVertex3f(obj.l_coords[0],obj.l_coords[1],obj.l_coords[2])
        glVertex3f(obj.l_coords[3],obj.l_coords[4],obj.l_coords[5])
        glEnd()     
        glPopMatrix()

def updateViz(self,vals):
    inds = digitize(vals,colrMapVals)
    for i in range(0,len(self.vizObjects)):
        self.vizObjects[i].r,self.vizObjects[i].g,self.vizObjects[i].b= colorMap[inds[i]-1]

def translate(self, _trans):
    self.makeCurrent()
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslated(_trans[0], _trans[1], _trans[2])
    glMultMatrixd(self.modelview_matrix_)
    self.modelview_matrix_ = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
    self.translate_vector_[0] = self.modelview_matrix_[3][0]
    self.translate_vector_[1] = self.modelview_matrix_[3][1]
    self.translate_vector_[2] = self.modelview_matrix_[3][2]

def rotate(self, _axis, _angle):
    #self.modelview_matrix_ = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
    t = [self.modelview_matrix_[0][0] * self.center_[0] +
         self.modelview_matrix_[1][0] * self.center_[1] +
         self.modelview_matrix_[2][0] * self.center_[2] +
         self.modelview_matrix_[3][0],
         self.modelview_matrix_[0][1] * self.center_[0] +
         self.modelview_matrix_[1][1] * self.center_[1] +
         self.modelview_matrix_[2][1] * self.center_[2] +
         self.modelview_matrix_[3][1],
         self.modelview_matrix_[0][2] * self.center_[0] +
         self.modelview_matrix_[1][2] * self.center_[1] +
         self.modelview_matrix_[2][2] * self.center_[2] +
         self.modelview_matrix_[3][2]]

    self.makeCurrent()
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslatef(t[0], t[1], t[2])
    glRotated(_angle, _axis[0], _axis[1], _axis[2])
    glTranslatef(-t[0], -t[1], -t[2])
    glMultMatrixd(self.modelview_matrix_)
    self.modelview_matrix_ = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

def keyPressEvent(self, ev):
    if (ev.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left):
        self.translate([-0.25, 0.0, 0.0])
        self.updateGL()
    elif (ev.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right):
        self.translate([0.25, 0.0, 0.0])
        self.updateGL()
    elif (ev.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_A):
        self.rotate([1.0, 0.0, 0.0],2.0)
        self.updateGL()
    elif (ev.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Q):
        self.rotate([1.0, 0.0, 0.0],-2.0)
        self.updateGL()
```

I use PyQt4 and PyGLWidget

Comment: Where's the rotation? There are no matrix operations in the code above, other than mode-setting and identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks all right to me. I think the problem is caused by how you update the rotation and color. OpenGL is a state machine, you feed it with all kinds of info (vertex pos, color, etc) and things get rendered, so MAKE SURE updateVis and translate/rotate are called on EVERY FRAME.

maybe your rotation/translation depends on Qt's signal/event mechanism, and it's not called every frame?

Comment: yes. i do not call the rotation and translation every frame, it is a signal event as you put it. How do i do rotation otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: The way i use is to create a timer, and let it connect the timer event to the rendering and update function. here's my code using qt to render opengl in c++, hope it helps: http://code.google.com/p/rayframe/source/browse/src/Launcher/MyGLWidget.cpp

Comment: Yes, i now have a separate timer that triggers updateViz function. And  it works seamlessly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is not a scene graph, in which you update rotation or translation. Those glRotate, glTranslate calls, they are meant to be called from the drawing function **NOT** in a event handler. Update some variables in the event handler, issue a redraw and then in the drawing code call glTranslate/glRotate according to the values in the variable.

Comment: I have changed the code as you suggested. Instead of the rotate and translate function, i update, variables via Qt. And call gluLootAt(variables) in the render func call. This however does not change my outcome. Even now, I do not see the translations simultaneously with color changes. Can you point me to any example?